# Get current position of an element within the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find an elements current position within the DOM (preferably when clicked).

With jQuery, I get it if I know the position beforehand:

`$('li').get(3);`

But there are times when I rely on `$(this)` to get the current position:

HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/JBjeg/

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
 $('li').click(function(){

     // this does not work
    console.log($(this).get());

    // this does, but I won't know which is clicked
    console.log($('li').get(3));

});
```

What's the best way for me to get the current position? Preferably as a number, so I can use it elsewhere.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use index:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

And also, you can use $.each:

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    console.log([$(this), index]);
});
```

Comment: That's great. Say I've got a list of images elsewhere, how would I get the matching index? (I click the second `li`, I need the second `img`)

Comment: say `index` holds the index, you just call `$('img').get(index)`

Comment: @tmyie See my answer, I have updated according to your comment!

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that it returns undefined on the matching item: http://jsfiddle.net/JBjeg/4/

Comment: .get() returns the actual DOM element, rather than jQuery object. You need to recast it: `$($('p').get(i)).show()` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/JBjeg/5/))

Comment: That's great. How come I have to recast it?

Comment: Because `$('p')` retrieves a jQuery object, which has `.show()` as one of its functions in its prototype. `$('p').get(0)` will retrieve the pure DOM element, not it's jQuery manifestation. It will only have DOM properties, such as `.style.display`. If you recast it, you will be using its jQuery reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the number of clicked element.

```
$(this).index();
```

Index will be Starting from `0`

```
$('li').click(function(){
     // this does not work
    console.log($(this).get());   
    // Will get index
    console.log($(this).index());
    // this does, but I won't know which is clicked
    console.log($('li').get(3)); 
});
```

**Update**

According to your comment in the last answer

If you want image related to index of  the clicked `li` you may try this

```
var index = $(this).index(); // Get index
var img = $("img").get(index); // image selector may vary
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JBjeg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**.index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

> Search for a given element from among the matched elements.

Example

```
$("li").index('ul')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index):

```
$('li').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

([updated demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBjeg/2/))